# Destination host unreachable, but the errorlevel is 0 (from a win7)

Tags: windows-7, ping

From a windows 7 machine, I ping a non existing ip address.

C:>ping 192.168.1.222

Pinging 192.168.1.222 with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 192.168.1.222: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 192.168.1.222: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 192.168.1.222: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.222:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss)

Even though there is no reply, the errorlevel is set to 0.

**what I am trying to do, is figure out if a remote machine is replying to ping. One of my test is to turn off the machine and ping it. For some reason, ping sets errorlevel to 0 **

Comment: Ping completed successfully.  You asked it to ping an IP address, and it did it.  The fact that no replies were received does not mean that the ping didn't work.

Comment: It behaved differently in win XP

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/403905/ping-from-windows-7-get-no-reply-but-sets-errorlevel-to-0

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of the *ping* command through *find* to see if the ping had a reply: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=304609